# Why can't I comment attributes in XAML?

Tags: xaml, attributes, comments

This has been bothering me for a while, maybe I am missing something.

The following throws an error with the commented attribute (expected >), but shouldn't I be able to do something like this?

```
<Label x:Name="Gaga"
               FontSize="20"
               <!--
               Content="{Binding SomethingThatIsEmptyAtDesignTime"}
                -->
               Content="LookAtMe!"
               />
```

Comment: WPF: one step forward, two steps back. It's all over WPF, isn't it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Though you can't comment out using the basic XAML markup, you can achieve the desired results by importing the Open XML markup namespace.

```
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
mc:Ignorable="ignore"

<Label x:Name="Gaga"
       FontSize="20"
       ignore:Content="{Binding SomethingThatIsEmptyAtDesignTime}"
       Content="LookAtMe!"
/>
```

This [blog post](https://galasoft.ch/posts/2010/02/quick-tip-commenting-out-properties-in-xaml) describes how to do it.

Comment: The link to the blog post is broken. The [blog post is now here](https://galasoft.ch/posts/2010/02/quick-tip-commenting-out-properties-in-xaml).

Comment: @FlyingFoX fixed

Answer (score 25):

short answer: because a `<` char is  not allowed between `<` and `>` (by XML definition).

The next question should be **"How can I comment out an XML/XAML attribute"**

The solution (e.g. in MS Blend/Visual Studio) is an `mc:Ignorable` attribute.

```
<RootElement
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DataContext="this is an attribute for design time only"
>
```

*From VS2015+ only specific attributes are supported, but read more below...*

To be more usefull you can have more as one ignorable prefix:

```
<RootElement
    xmlns   ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:rem ="ignorable"
    xmlns:TODO ="ignorable"
    xmlns:DISABLED ="ignorable"
    xmlns:NOTE ="ignorable"
    mc:Ignorable="d rem TODO DISABLED NOTE"         
    rem:Background="this is also ignored (commented out)"
    TODO:Background=" (commented as TODO)"
    DISABLED:Background="this is also ignored (commented as DISABLED)"
>
```

The "tokens" `rem` `TODO` `DISABLED` `NOTE` are only suggestion of me and any other (valid xml names) are possible.

practical sample in any element:

```
<TextBox
    DISABLED:Background="#FF000000"  NOTE:Background="temporary disabled"
    Background="#FFFFFF"             TODO:Background="specify an other background"
    TODO:TextBox="complete the textbox"
>
```

Usage of unicode chars:

The following list of unicode chars are valid for xml name:

`ᆞ` `ᅳ` `ǀ` `ǁ` `ǂ` `ǃ` `ᅀ`

```
<TextBox
    ǃ:Background="temporary disabled"
    ǂ:Background="temporary disabled"
    ǁ:Background="temporary disabled"
>
```

Usage as documentation (XML comments)

```
<RootElement
    ...
    xmlns:doc="ignorable"
    mc:Ignorable="... doc ..." 
    
    <MyControl
        doc.summary="shows my control"
        doc.remarks="any remarks..."
    />
>
```

**Update** for VS 2015 and later

*examples above has been updated*

Because the namespace `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"` is validated by VS now, you can use it only for the defined members.
But you can specify an own namespace e.g. `xmlns:rem="ignorable"` und use the prefix `rem` or any other user defined prefix to make comments without the VS designer error.
*Tested with VS 2019*

Comment: This solution trips up the designer in Visual Studio 2015. Putting `comment:NotAnAttribute="should be a comment"` in a UserControl stops the designer from rendering that UserControl. Runtime behavior is fine though.

Answer (score 8):

Because XAML is XML-based, and [XML doesn't allow comments inside other markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-comments). It's unfortunate, I agree; XML commenting leaves much to be desired.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a comment like that inside an element.

This is true to all XML, not just XAML.

Take a look at the [XML Comments](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments) specification, which explicitly disallows this kind of markup.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments

Comments can exist anywhere within the document, outside of other markup.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't. XML doesn't work that way - a comment node isn't an attribute, and so it can't go where attributes should be.

Answer (score 0):

I saw an interesting approach to commenting out properties at [Laurent Bugnion's blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2010/02/01/quick-tip-commenting-out-properties-in-xaml.aspx).

Essentially, he defines an "ignore" namespace, then adds the "ignore" prefix to any property that he wants to ignore.

```
<ignore:ThisBlockIsIgnored Hello="World" Again="Blah">
<Label Content="No parse" />
</ignore:ThisBlockIsIgnored>
```