# This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint

Tags: android, xml, comments, warnings

I get the warning, "This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint" When I modify a copy of a tutorial code (below)

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

This works fine, and the warning only comes up if a new blank line is created

I've modified it for a friend with several comments lines explaining what each part of it does however, whenever i add in an extra line in the above (Even a blank line, in this case it's a comment line) I receive the above error

```
<!--edit text creates a text input box-->
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
<!-- edit_message is a variable, defined in   strings.xml-->
<!-- determines the width of the textField, in this case 0dp means "however long the text is" IE: it will grow to fit however many characters the user types -->
    android:layout_width="0dp"
<!-- determines the height of the Text Field -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
<!-- The hint is the default value for the text field, it calls on the variable edit_message defined in strings.xml-->
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
<!-- Weight means how much the screen the text field can take up, in this case, the ratio is 1:1 so it can take up however much room is needed, However if a different variable also had the weight of 1, the ratio would be 1:2 and each could take up half the screen -->
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Without the comments, the warning is not there

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't have your comments break the xml element. I.e. you can't put comments inbetween `<EditText` and `/>`. [A similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16904880/1029225), with coicidentally the same code snippet, was recently answered.

Answer (score 20):

The Reason for this warning is that you haven't set the inputType for this editText. Add the following line:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

So it should look like this:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

And the warning is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Logically you should get warning in the line 
`<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"`
and an error in the next line.

***Reason:***
When you are placing comment tags, then the closing tag of comment is considered as the illegal closing tag for `EditText`. So you should even get the following error

`Element type "EditText" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".`

and because of the above error the remaining code is not executed and thus you get a warning

```
This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint
```

even though `android:hint` attribute exists in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I just run your code and got my app running properly, when i added the comment it crashes, then i realized that you should not comment inside your XML , it is a principle of XML.

I suggest you to read this article explaning what is a well formed XML and how to comment xml in the right way http://webdesign.about.com/cs/xmlinformation/ht/htcommentxml.htm
Also here has been a discussion about this particularly subject and has been solved as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2073162/2069737

Hope it helps you.